# Embed availablility form in a booking form

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am developing a rental bike platform and I'm in stucked in the booking form (step 2).

In the first step the user selected the dates for the booking and their personal data. In the second step, they may choose the number of bikes they want to rent based on a form with a choice widget from 0 to x (up to the bikes available on that dates).

The thing is I don't know how to manage this form. By now, I have a "BookingType" what has a collection of "Bike" entity. The user, at that moment, can choose which bike they want to rent but not the quantity. Would you create a "BookingBikeType" containing on Bike and the BookingType will containt a collection of this new "BookingBikeType"??

If it helps, I pasted the schema and Type of Booking:

```
BEM\ReservaBundle\Entity\Reserva:
type: entity
table: null
fields:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
    inici:
        type: datetime
    fi:
        type: datetime
    import:
        type: float
        nullable: true        
manyToMany:
    bicicletes:
      targetEntity: BEM\BikeBundle\Entity\Bike
oneToMany:
    reserva_personalitzacio:
      targetEntity: ReservaPersonalitzacio
      mappedBy: reserva
manyToOne:
    client:
      targetEntity: BEM\ClientBundle\Entity\Client
      cascade: [persist]
    lloc_recollida:
      targetEntity: ReservaLlocRecollida          

lifecycleCallbacks: {  }



class ReservaType extends AbstractType {
private $translator;

public function __construct($translator = null) {
  $this->translator = $translator;      
}


public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('inici', null, array(
            'widget'=>'single_text',
            'format'=>'yyyy-MM-dd',
            'attr'=>array('class'=>'diaInicio',
                          'placeholder'=>(($this->translator === null) ? '' : $this->translator->trans('Fecha inicio')),
                          'readonly'=>'readonly'  
                          )
            ))
        ->add('fi', null, array(
            'widget'=>'single_text',
            'format'=>'yyyy-MM-dd',
            'attr'=>array('class'=>'diaFinal',
                          'placeholder'=>(($this->translator === null) ? '' : $this->translator->trans('Fecha final')),
                          'readonly'=>'readonly'
                         )
            ))
        ->add('import')
        ->add('lloc_recollida', null, array('empty_value'=>false))            
        ->add('nou_lloc_recollida', new ReservaLlocRecollidaType($this->translator), array('required'=>false))
        ->add('client', new ClientType($this->translator))
        ->add('bicicletes')
        //->add('bicicletes', new ReservaBicicletaType())
    ;
}
```

For each bike selected in step 2, it will create as many ReservaPersonalitzacio where the user can customize their booking as "height of the bike", "size of wheels", etc.

So? How would you solve the exposed problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're talking already about **steps** within your form process I suggest to use the CraueFormFlowBundle for this. Here you have the possibility to build a form type for each step in your form process. https://github.com/craue/CraueFormFlowBundle

You could solve the problem as follows:

Order Entity:

- User (N Order has 1 User)
- Collection of BikesOrders (1 Order has N BikeOrder)
- (Maybe total price)

BikeOrder Entity:

- OrderEntity (N BikeOrder has 1 Order)
- BikeEntity (N BikeOrder has 1 Bike)
- Quantity
- All your settings (e.g. height, ...)

Bike Entity:

- Name
- Brand
- ...

That's just a way you can do relations with orders and products. Customize it to your needs -  especially if you want bidirectional or unidirectional association mapping is up to you.